# Как узнать критическая была ошибка или нет?

Tags: javascript

В гугл аналитике есть такой параметр для их функции: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/exceptions?hl=ru

> Имеет значение true, если исключение было критическим.

Но ведь в самом объекте ошибки нет указания на критичность. Там есть только:

- message
- fileName
- lineNumber

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Если отлавливать ошибки через `onerror` там так же нет никакой "критичности":

- Сообщение ошибки (string)
- Url, где произошла ошибка (string)
- Номер строки, где прошизошла ошибка (number)
- Номер столбца для строки, в которой произошла ошибка (number)
- Error Object (object)

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: в данном случае ты сам должен определять как отметить ошибку в аналитике, как фатальную или нет

Comment: @Grundy Я подозревал что тут какой то подвох.